# Как найти индекс первого элемента в отсортированном Series объекте?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

То есть, я сгенерировал один и тот же список `s`.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
    
r = np.random.RandomState(1)
s = pd.Series(r.uniform(0, 10, 100))
```

Хочу найти индекс первого элемента в отсортированном `s`, где значения больше 5. Посчитав сам, ближе к 5 это индекс с номером 67, но как его найти через написания кода?

Comment: +1 за отличный воспроизводимый пример данных )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться функцией [numpy.searchsorted()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html):

```
In [19]: np.searchsorted(s.sort_values(), 5 + 1e-8)
Out[19]: 51
```

PS `+ 1e-8` (эпсилон) - нужен для того, чтобы обеспечить **строгое** сравнение.

Comment: Каких только функций в нумпае нет. Каждый раз что-то новое узнаю ))

Comment: @CrazyElf, а если вдруг покажется что знаете уже всё, то обязательно напишут новые)

Answer (score 3):

```
s = s.sort_values().reset_index(drop=True) # см. примечание внизу про индекс
print(s[s > 5][:1])
```

Вывод этого элемента (с индексом):

```
51    5.148891
dtype: float64
```

Если просто индекс:

```
print(s[s > 5].index[0])
```

Вывод:

```
51
```

А индекс вам нужен уже в отсортированной `Series` по порядку или в исходной до сортировки? Если в исходной, то уберите `.reset_index(drop=True)`, но я не очень понимаю, в чём тогда смысл всего этого. Тогда действительно получится `67`.

Comment: Не правильно пояснил суть задания, да индекс нужен уже в отсортированной `Series`